# Laravel API Based ionic application not working on android but its working fine on browser

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, laravel-8, laravel-api

This is my code. its perfectly works on browser. But it doesn't works at mobile. Please help me to solve this problem. I am using laravel api to get json output.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';

@Injectable()
export class AccessProviders  {
    server: string = 'https://sriex.com/api/';
    constructor(
        public http: HttpClient,
    ){
        
    }
    postData(body,file,user_token){
        let type = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
        let token = "Bearer "+user_token;
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': type,'Authorization': token});
        let options = {
            headers: headers
        }
        return this.http.post(this.server+file,JSON.stringify(body),options).map(res => res);
       // return this.http.post(this.server + file,JSON.stringify(body),options)
        //.timeout(59000)
        //.map(res => res);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error ur facing?

Comment: No issues. but not working on android